# How to prepopulate form with data passed from @object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my website a user can upload "inspirations" aka images or text that a user finds inspirational.

I want to create a feature, like *Pinterest*, where a user can click on a image or text to "pin it" instead of having to upload his own.

[image]

Upon clicking the button I want the user to be redirected to **inspirations/_form** with the appropriate fields populated.

[image]

For example, I tried passing it in the path with `new_inspiration_path({image: inspiration.image})`, but that didn't have an effect.

```
<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| %>
  <%= link_to new_inspiration_path, data: { modal: true } do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(inspiration.image.url(:medium)), inspiration %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign this object in your controller action, something like this:

```
def new
  @inspiration = Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id])
end
```

And the path should be:

```
new_inspiration_path(inspiration_id: inspiration.id)
```

Comment: The problem may be in your controller create action or something in your form view code.

Comment: Seems you need something like this
`if params[:inspiration_id] 
  @inspiration = Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id]) 
else
  @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build
end`
Sorry for code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you duplicating functionality?

If someone "pins" an inspiration, is it not the case that the inspiration will be the same one the other user uploaded? Which means, you should have functionality to create a *pin*, not an *inspiration*.

---

I'll delete this if out of context, but here's what I'd do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :inspirations do
   match :pin, via: [:post, :delete], on: :member #-> url.com/inspirations/:id/pin
end

#app/controllers/inspirations_controller.rb
class InspirationsController < ApplicationController
   def pin
      @inspiration = Inspiration.find params[:id]
      if request.post?
         current_user.pins << @inspiration
      elsif request.delete?
         current_user.pins.delete @inspiration
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
#app/views/inspirations/index.html.erb
<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| %>
   <%= link_to "Pin", inspiration_pin_path(inspiration) %>
<% end %>
```

--

If you wanted to add extra attributes for the "pin" (such as a custom caption etc), you'll be able to do it with a simple form...

```
#app/views/inspirations/index.html.erb
<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| %>
   <%= form_for inspiration, url: inspiration_pin_path(inspiration) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :caption %>
      <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```