# .find & .built with new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, controller, submit

I use this path: `new_inspiration_path(inspiration_id: inspiration.id)` to take info from an existing inspiration and pre-populate a new form so a user can duplicate the inspiration just by clicking the path route and then submit.

But my problem is that once the form is submitted the new inspiration isn't created.

```
  def new
    if params[:inspiration_id]
      @inspiration = Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id])
    end
    @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build
  end

  def create
    @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build(inspiration_params)
    @inspiration.save
  end
```

This is because @inspiration is stuck trying to do two different things: `.find` and `.built`. How can we do both when `params[:inspiration_id]`?

Question inspired by: [How to prepopulate form with data passed from @object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701303/how-to-prepopulate-form-with-data-passed-from-object/34701838?noredirect=1#comment57172881_34701838)

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as shown, is not using `@inspirational`. You need to pass `@inspirational.attributes.slice(Inspiration.attribute_names)` `Inspiration.new` to copy all pertinent attributes to the new object:

```
if params[:inspiration_id]
  @inspirational = Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id])
  inspirational_attributes = @inspirational.attributes.slice(Inspiration.attribute_names)
end

@inspiration = current_user.inspirations.new(inspirational_attributes)
```

Of course, make sure `inspirational_attributes` is set to `{}` when `params[:inspiration_id]` is not set.

Comment: That was a typo. I meant to say just `inspiration` for all, but maybe it would work if I made a distinction using `inspiration` and `inspirational`. I plugged in your code as is and by taking off the ending `al` from `inspirational`, but either way the code doesn't populate the _form. Maybe it is because I'm misunderstanding your "of course" paragraph. Sorry can you please elaborate Leito? Thanks so much for the help man!

Comment: You say the form doesn't populate, but does inspirational_attributes have the values you want? We need to make sure that is working before worrying about the form. I just meant that that `inspirational_attributes = {}` should be before the `if`, so you don't get a "NameError: undefined local variable or method `inspirational_attributes'"

Comment: Yea I'm just putting `Inspiration.name` for `attribute_names` and when I click on the path I am brought to the new _form where it remains unpopulated. No errors come up tho. And thanks for the clarification Leito :)

Comment: Ah you have `@inspirational.attributes.slice` etc. Is `attributes` there just a placeholder since I don't define it anywhere else?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, attributes comes from the the class your model is inheriting: `ActiveRecord::Base`. Let's not turn this into a chat. Search about debugging, hint: search for `byebug` or simply learn how to troubleshoot using `puts var_name` (outputting to the rails server output), so on top of errors you can see what values variables hold before the form is rendered.