# How to find @object and then duplicate @object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The below code [prepopulates a new _form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701303/how-to-prepopulate-form-with-data-passed-from-object/34701838#34701838), but once the user saves the form  it will update the old `Inspiration` instead of creating a new `Inspiration`.

### controller

```
  def new
    if params[:inspiration_id] 
      @inspiration = Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id]) 
      @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build # Is there a way to find and then build?
    else 
      @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build
    end
  end
```

### path

```
new_inspiration_path(inspiration_id: inspiration.id)
```

How can we use `@inspiration` to first `Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id])` then to `current_user.inspirations.build`?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `edit` for updating and `new` for just creating?

Comment: @tejasbubane I want to use `new` for creating. I'm using find in new so that I can find a featured inspiration and then when the user clicks the above path the idea is that the `text` of that featured inspiration will prepopulate the new form. That works. Now once the user saves that prepopulated form it doesn't create a new Inspiration. It edits the featured inspiration, which I don't want.

Comment: Does the form post to the same action? I don't think so. It would be better if you edit the question and add your routes corresponding to this controller.

Comment: Routes are typical `resources :inspirations` so new, edit, update, delete, etc @tejasbubane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dup` method on the existing record if found. For example

```
existing_inspiration = Inspiration.find_by_id params[:inspiration_id]

if existing_inspiration
  @inspiration = existing_inspiration.dup
else
  @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build
end
```

Comment: Thanks Bart. I'm working on your suggestion now. Question tho. For some reason only the `:name` attribute is duplicated into the _form, but not the `:image` or `:tag_list` attributes. Any idea why? Thanks good sir!

Comment: `dup` will only perform a shallow copy of the existing object's attributes. If `:image` and `:tag_list` are associations, they'll need to be assigned manually after the `existing_inspiration.dup` line.

Comment: Thanks Bart. When you say assign manually do you mean something like       `@inspiration.image = params[:image]` &
      `@inspiration.tag_list = params[:tag_list]`. Sorry

Comment: Well if you're trying to copy it over from the `existing_inspiration` then it would be `@inspiration.image = existing_inspiration.image` etc.

Comment: I can see why `:tag_list` still isn't working since it's an association (it was working in the question code tho), but I can't see why `:image` doesnt work. Maybe because it is kind of redundant to say @inspiration.image = existing_inspiration.image since we made `@inspiration = existing_inspiration.dup`?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what `:tag_list` and `:image` actually are and how you're actually setting them in the form. I would suggest you create a new question detailing the above and go from there. Please accept the answer if it answered your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Good point. Thank you :) I'll continue the conversation over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664978/how-to-prepopulate-form-with-duplicated-image Hopefully you'll stop by!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your Inspiration is updated is because it is a persisted record. You could extract all attributes except the `id` and instantiate a new inspiration.

```
original = Inspiration.find(params[:inspiration_id])
@inspiration = Inspiration.new(original.attributes.except("id"))
```

I assume that you want to create a copy of an inspiration in order to have some fields prepopulated.
Depending on your exact requirements it might or might not be a good idea to copy the inspiration like that (references to other objects, permissions/access, ...)

Comment: I couldn't get the image attribute with your code, but thanks for trying :) I continued the problem over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664978/how-to-prepopulate-form-with-duplicated-image. I gave the answer to Bart even though both your answers achieved the same thing because I saw his first (I wish I had a better reason lol sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% of your use case as you generally dont pass IDs into `new` actions. However, you might check out [clone](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone) if you want a new object based on all of the attributes of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to redirect to edit action instead of going to the new action to follow rails CRUD structure. Let me know if you need more.